# How to put char ('X') to int array?

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application, tic-tac-toe

Hi I have 2D array type of int where I have numbers, for example from 1 to 100.

It's a game - something like Tic-Tac-Toe - but I use bigger array. So I need to put a character 'X' or 'O' from user to this array. But problem is I can't (don't know) how to put these characters in that int array. I wan to use only the console.

I tried make the array type of char but then I can't fill the array with numbers.

I know how to do it if user would have want put some numbers but then It doesn't look good...

I would be happy for any advice how to do it.

```
public void Napln () { //filling the array
        int poc = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < pole.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
            for (int j = 0; j < pole.GetLength(0); j++)
            {
                if (poc < 10)
                    Console.Write(" " + (pole[j, i] = poc++) + "  | ");
                else if ( poc < 100 )               
                    Console.Write( (pole[j,i] = poc ++) + "  | ");
                else                    
                    Console.Write((pole[j, i] = poc++) + " | ");                    
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            for ( int v = 0; v < roz1; v ++ )
                Console.Write("_____|");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

 public void Pozice (int vyber) //find the user choice 
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < pole.GetLength(1); i ++ )
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < pole.GetLength(0); j ++ )
            {
                if (pole[i, j] == vyber)
                {
                    pole[i, j] = 'X';          
                    hraci.Vypis();
                }
            }
        }
    }
 public void Vypis() //print the same with change of user choice
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < pole.GetLength(1); i ++ )
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
            for ( int j = 0; j < pole.GetLength(0); j ++ )
            {
                if (pole[j,i] < 10)
                    Console.Write(" " + pole[j, i] + "  | ");
                else if (pole[j,i] < 100)
                    Console.Write(pole[j, i] + "  | ");
                else
                    Console.Write(pole[j, i] + " | ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int v = 0; v < roz1; v++)
                Console.Write("_____|");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

I am the new one in C# especially the OOP. So if you have any more advice I would be happy.

Comment: ***Show Code***

Comment: Why do you need to fill the board with numbers?

Comment: but you can put numbers in chars?

Comment: Why cant you just use `arr[0] = 'X'`? `char` has an implicit conversion to `int`

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: You probably looking for array of {int, CellState} pairs where  CellState is enum like Empty, Cross, Zero... If you clarify how number and 'X' should co-exist in one cell someone may produce an answer.

Comment: Why are you trying to put a non int into an int array? If you want something that's not numeric, make the array a string or char array.

Answer (score 0):

Just taking your question as it is, I can imagine two ways I'd do it without getting too fancy.

The first one would be to use two arrays. One for holding the numbers (and int array), one for holding the player input (a char array holding "x" and "o"). This could look like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int width = 10;
        int height = 10;

        char[,] playerBoard = new char[width, height];
        int[,] numberedBoard = new int[width, height];

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                // Fill the numbered board with 1 to 100
                numberedBoard[x, y] = x * width + y + 1;

                // And the player board with emptyness
                playerBoard[x, y] = ' ';
            }
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine("Number at x = 3 / y = 5: " + numberedBoard[3, 5]);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Current owner of x = 3 / y = 5: \"" + playerBoard[3, 5] + "\"");

        // Let's change the owner of x = 3 and y = 5
        playerBoard[3, 5] = 'X';

        System.Console.WriteLine("New owner of x = 3 / y = 5: \"" + playerBoard[3, 5] + "\"");
    }
}
```

A second solution could be to create an object to fit your needs, and have an array of this one. The benefit is that you only have one array, and each cell holds all the information relevant to this cell. Consider the following:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    struct BoardEntry {
        public int number;
        public char owner;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        int width = 10;
        int height = 10;

        BoardEntry[,] board = new BoardEntry[width, height];

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                // For each "cell" of the board, we create a new instance of
                // BoardEntry, holding the number for this cell and a possible ownage.
                board[x, y] = new BoardEntry() {
                    number = x * width + y + 1,
                    owner = ' '
                };
            }
        }

        // You can access each of those instances with `board[x,y].number` and `board[x,y].owner`

        System.Console.WriteLine("Number at x = 3 / y = 5: " + board[3, 5].number);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Current owner of x = 3 / y = 5: \"" + board[3, 5].owner + "\"");

        // Let's change the owner of x = 3 and y = 5
        board[3, 5].owner = 'X';
        System.Console.WriteLine("New owner at x = 3 / y = 5: \"" + board[3, 5].owner + "\"");
    }
}
```

It seems like you are new to programming, so the first solution might be easier to understand and use right now, but I suggest you read at some point a little bit into what `struct`s and `class`es are, because they let you do some really powerful things, like in this case bundle the relevant information that belongs together.